# Meta viewport breaks responsibility (makes everything very small)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have wordpress blog: https://blog.sznapka.pl on which I'd like to fix responsiveness on mobile.
Without meta viewport, it looks pretty much okay. Only thing I want to fix, to make the header 100% and content to have a margin on the right. But can't do that, because CSS media queries are not respected. I've added debug:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #header-bottom {background: pink !important}
}
```

[image: without meta viewport]

When I use  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` The layout is "zoomed-out" and looks very bad, but media queries are being respected.

[image: with meta viewport]

Anyone have an idea of how to make it display properly, with meta viewport enabled, so Media Queries works but without that ugly zoom-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#footer #footer-content` uses 960px instead of 100%. Also your `#footer-content2-left` and `#footer-content2-right` use fixed width's aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works like it should `<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />`  however I had to adjust some styles with media queries.